# Using OpenCV output in a Web Browser

Tags: php, opencv

Thanks for taking the time to read my post.

I have written a small app that does some image tracking using OpenCV which I am reasonably pleased with. It's not ground breaking, it just calculates optical flow.

My question is, is there a way I can get opencv to run on my server and control it through a web browser?

i have a 1&1 linux hosting subscription and in my mind, I was wondering if could I redirect the cvShowImage("Window",img) command to show the image back to a window. I was thinking perhaps upload the entire .exe and execute it from the browser - but i don't know.

as you can tell, I have absolutely zip experience with server programming and web dev etc.

Any input would be greatly appreciated and received.

Thanks, Kay

Answer (score 0):

If you are aware of PHP, you can do it. 
You can see the output in browser since php is a scripting language.

[OpenCV for PHP](https://github.com/mgdm/OpenCV-for-PHP) is a PHP extension wrapping the OpenCV library for image processing. It lets you use the OpenCV library for image recognition and modification tasks.

It requires PHP 5.3, and OpenCV 2.0 or above.